# Difference between peek and receive (azure service bus)

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Does anyone knows the difference between the receive and peek options in azure service bus?

```
var client = new MessageReceiver("ServiceBusConnectionString", "Queue");

// difference between this one:
var peekResults =  await client.PeekAsync(100);

// and this one
var receiveResults = await client.ReceiveAsync(100);
```

I see I can get the same results, but I want to know which one should I use and why? so internally what would be the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peek will fetch messages w/o increasing delivery counter. It's a way to "preview" messages w/o removing from the queue.

Receive will increase the delivery counter. When received in `ReceiveAndDelete` mode, messages will be gone from the queue. With `PeekLock` mode messages will remain on the queue unless `MaxDeliveryCount` was exceeded and they will be dead-lettered.